# Plot eigenvectors on scatter plot

Tags: pca, matlab, scatterplot, eigenvalues

I have a problem and need some assistance. I have a scatter plot of two variables $x, y$, and I want to plot the eigenvectors on it. I tried one methods plotting each eigenvector as a line equation but it didn't work. Can somebody show me how to plot them in Matlab?

Thanks

Eigenvectors:

- `eign1 = [-0.7352 0.6779]`
- `eign2 = [0.6779 0.7352]`

Figure of scatter plot:

[image]

Comment: Could you add your dataset as well?

Comment: There are two sorts of nonredundant eigenvectors - left (`10x2`) and right (`2x2`) - which do you want to plot? In other words, how many points do you want to add to the picture? Also, are you sure you want to plot in the space defined by axes-variables? or maybe you are speaking of the space of the principal axes?

Comment: x = [2.5 0.5 2.2 1.9 3.1 2.3 2 1 1.5 1.1];
y = [2.4 0.7 2.9 2.2 3.0 2.7 1.6 1.1 1.6 0.9];  Data x, y. I am speaking of the space of Principal Axes.

Comment: If you want to plot both 10 observation points and 2 variable points in the space of the 2 principal axes - search "biplot" on this site or matlab docs or elsewhere.

Comment: You mean the eigenvectors of the data covariance, correct?

Comment: yes, i mean eigenvector of covariance data @A.Donda

Comment: Let me check 'biplot', look interesting to me. @ttnphns